# Не удается присвоить числовое значение полю

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу присвоить числовое значение полю, но на вот на такую простейшую запись выдает ошибку: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

```js
var number = 3;
$('.div').find(".input").val() = number;
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input" size="4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Означает: *«некорректная левая часть выражения, в котором присваивается значение»*. Синтаксис некорректный, потому что `$('.div').find(".input").val()` не является переменной или свойством объекта. Вместо этого

```
$('.div').find(".input").val() = number;
```

надо так:

```
$('.div').find(".input").val(number);
```

---

Демо:

```js
var number = 3;
$('.div').find(".input").val(number);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input" size="4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы установить новое значение, нужно передать в функцию val() параметр

```
var number = 3;
$('.div').find(".input").val(number);
```